# Camping and Brewing

Tags: brewing, oxidation, transport

So I have a big bumper pull camper that I travel around the country with.  I was thinking about a camping trip with some buddies and was considering the implications of perhaps starting a brew while we were waiting for the pork shoulder to come out of the smoker.

I am curious if anyone ever tried to start a brew while in the woods.

The camper has a full kitchen, to include a propane burner stove and an electric/propane operated fridge.

I would do this somewhere with full hookups to allow for all the waste and washing.  But I usually use water that I purchase in 2.5 gallon containers.

The way I figure, everything should be the same as it is at home except for one big thing.  Lets say I start my brew on a Saturday.  I will only be out there for a couple more days before it is time to pack up and go home.

I will need to transport my fermentor at about day two or three.  Will that be a problem?  I will probably use some sort of cooler strapped into the back seat of my truck to transport the carboy back to the house.  This should help with light and temperature fluctuations.  But it could be a couple hour drive and I am concerned with all the moving around.  The sediment should have time to settle again in my cellar once I get home, but could I oxidize the beer.

Will this be too risky?  Any suggestions are welcome and feel free to shoot down my idea in the first place.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem on fermenter transport.  Fermentation will still be going so no worries about oxidation.  But I'd recommend a bucket rather than a carboy.  Unbreakable.

Comment: Good point on the carboy.  I suppose a minor traffic accident would become a nightmare if I spilled 5 gallons of wort in my truck.